# Prevent modal from launching if form is empty

Tags: jquery, forms, modal-dialog, submit, required

I have a form in the footer of an html pointing to a form.php that delivers the fields info into an email.

[Link to page](http://nmuino.com.ar/detailers/index.html) (and scroll to the bottom)

I also have a thank you modal appearing after submission with a script that delays the submit to 5 seconds (to allow the user to read the thank you modal).

The problem is that if the user leaves the fields empty and presses the submit button, the modal is still showing up, and I want to avoid that.

I tried to disable the button if the fields are empty but It didn't work.

**Form code**

```
            <form method="post" action="form.php" class="form-horizontal" id="footer-contact-form">

                <fieldset>

                <!-- Text input-->
                <div class="form-group">
                  <div class="col-md-12">
                  <input id="name" name="name" type="text" placeholder="Full Name" class="form-control input-md" required>

                  </div>
                </div>

                <!-- Text input-->
                <div class="form-group">
                  <div class="col-md-12">
                  <input id="email" name="email" type="text" placeholder="Email Address" class="form-control input-md" required>

                  </div>
                </div>

                <!-- Text input-->
                <div class="form-group">
                  <div class="col-md-12">
                  <input id="subject" name="subject" type="text" placeholder="Subject" class="form-control input-md" required>

                  </div>
                </div>

                <!-- Textarea -->
                <div class="form-group">
                  <div class="col-md-12">                     
                    <textarea class="form-control" id="message" type="text" name="message" required placeholder="Message"></textarea>
                  </div>
                </div>

                <!-- Button -->
                <div class="form-group">
                  <div class="col-md-12">
                    <button id="Send-footer" type="submit" name="Send" class="btn btn-default btn-footer" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#thanks">Send</button>
                  </div>
                </div>

                </fieldset>
                </form>
```

**Script delaying the submission**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#footer-contact-form').submit(function (e) {
    var form = this;
    e.preventDefault();
    setTimeout(function () {
        form.submit();
    }, 5000); // in milliseconds
});
```

**Script I tried to disable the submit button (this currently DOES NOT WORK FOR ME, the button gets never enabled again)**

```
 <script>
$(document).ready(function (){
    validate();
    $('#name, #email, #subject, #message').change(validate);
});

function validate(){
    if ($('#name').val().length   >   0   &&
        $('#email').val().length  >   0   &&
        $('#subject').val().length  >   0   &&
        $('#message').val().length    >   0) {
        $("#Send-footer").prop("disabled", false);
    }
    else {
        $("#Send-footer]").prop("disabled", true);
    }
}
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried to see if it actually gets inside of the if/else?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try this? I'm not sure if calling the validate function without it's "()" will work, thus i imagine the validate called on document.ready is the only time it gets called.

```
$(document).on('change', '#name, #email, #subject, #message', function()
{
    validate();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually this script worked for disabling the submit button

```
 <script>
$('#Send-footer').attr('disabled', true);
$('input:text').keyup(function () {
    var disable = false;
       $('input:text').each(function(){
            if($(this).val()==""){
                 disable = true;                
            }
       });
  $('#Send-footer').prop('disabled', disable);
});
```